# Tag navigation using CTRL+] does not work with Non English keyboard on Windows

Tags: cursor-movement, microsoft-windows, tags, jumplist

When using *gVim* on *Windows 7* I cannot use **^]** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>) to jump to tags as described in the *Vim* documentation:

```
<C-LeftMouse>                   *<C-LeftMouse>* *CTRL-]*
CTRL-]      Jump to the definition of the keyword under the
            cursor.  Same as ":tag {ident}", where {ident} is the
            keyword under or after cursor.
            When there are several matching tags for {ident}, jump
            to the [count] one.  When no [count] is given the
            first one is jumped to. See |tag-matchlist| for
            jumping to other matching tags.
            {Vi: identifier after the cursor}
```

This used to bother me a lot when learning *Vim*. In the end I managed to solve it by using this hacky mapping

```
nnoremap <leader>t :tag <c-r><c-w><cr>
```

which allowed me to jump to tags using `\t` (I used the default setting of `\` as`<leader>`).

This is not a problem for me anymore as I now only use *gnu/linux* for programming and I have already read pretty much all help there is to read. But considering that this contributed to making my experience learning *Vim* so much worse I ask here to get this solved for people who are in the same situation I was in.

Why doesn't <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> work for me on *Windows 7* and how can it be fixed?

**Edit**: The title has been edited with the information that this problem is caused by the keyboard layout I used.

Comment: Can you provide more information? *Why* doesn't it work? Do you have ctags installed? What error message do you get, if any, when you try using `Ctrl-]` on a word?

Comment: I just managed to figure it out! The problem was because I used an keyboard layout that requires `^]` to be entered using `Ctrl-AltGr-9` which does not work within Vim. I answered my own question with this information.

Comment: FWIW, `<C-]>` on an AZERTY Mac keyboard is obtained by pressing `<C-$>`, `$` being in the same physical location as `]` on QWERTY keyboards.

Comment: I remember a solution which involved using MS Keyboard Layout Creator to "inject" the key combination (i.e. the OS didn't generate a key code at all when `Ctrl-]` was pressed. Or was it for `Ctrl-[` ?)

Comment: @romainl: thanks for mentioning this. Reminded me of my own question I asked on SO on this topic. Answered by... you :-)

Comment: I've had similar problems in my Portuguese keyboard (but in Linux) and the solution was to pause between key presses. That is, if I press Ctrl, then wait, press AltGr, then wait, and finally press 9 this shortcut will work! Don't know why, though...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say hello to knowledge fragmentation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932702/520162 This question was already asked and answered on StackOverflow.

**The key is to  press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and the key that is located where the <kbd>]</kbd> lives on the US keyboard**. I had the issue with a QUERTZ German keyboard and have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>

Compare: US keyboard:
[image: US keyboard]

German keyboard:
[image: German keyboard]

Another obvious way would be to simply remap the functionality to a different keystroke. Since you want to g**o** t**o** the tag under the cursor, you could use <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> for this:

```
:map oo <C-]>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out why I had this problem.

## The cause of the problem

The problem is that I used a Non-English keyboard layout on my Windows 7 computer.

The backslash character is entered using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> on my Non-English keyboard layout. This leads to that **^]** would be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. This simply does not work within *Vim*.

I do not know why that is:

- The problem could be in hardware. Maybe the problem is caused by limited keyboard ghosting (but I have the same problem with a keyboard that is supposed to be able to register 6 keys at once).
- The problem could be in software. Vim maybe was not programmed with this in mind.

I would appreciate if someone else who uses a Non-English keyboard could comment on if **^]** works as it should on their machine.

## The solution

The problem is fixed by simply changing to an English keyboard layout. Unfortunately I have found no other solution.

So you have to use an English layout instead. *Vim*'s user interface is also designed with an English keyboard layout in mind. Using an English keyboard layout is also advantageous in programming because characters like `[`, `{` and `;` that are frequently used in programming become easier to reach (no <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> stretch). So switching can even make your life more comfortable!

The problem will be about entering characters in your main language. Then you have to resort to using **digraphs** (see `:help digraphs`).

Another way to solve it this problem would be to use this hacky mapping that was mentioned in the question:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :tag <c-r><c-w><cr>
```

Which allows the user to jump to a tag with `\t` (if `<leader>` is set to `\` as it is by default).

Comment: This is no solution, this is surrender.